# How to pick only one consumer from pact broker while running provider side tests

Tags: gradle, pact

I want to pick only one consumer while running my provider side of tests not all the consumers present in PACT  hasPactsFromPactBroker('http://pact-broker')

hasPactsFromPactBroker('http://pact-broker')
hasPactWith('scrape-api')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the pact-jvm maintainer but I believe there is a filter you can use. Have a look in the docs. Otherwise, just give it the URL of the one pact you want to verify. eg `http://broker/pacts/provider/PROVIDER/consumer/CONSUMER/latest`

Comment: thank Beth.  I tried giving the url of only one pact but still pactVerify running tests on all consumers.  I will have a deeper look into documentation if I can see any filter.